# Why does calling the set function of a useState hook apply immediately in async functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I experienced different behaviors when calling multiple set functions of a useState hook in sync and async functions.

```
function Test() {
    console.log('app rendering starts.');
    const [a, setA] = useState(1);
    const [b, setB] = useState(11);
    const updateState = () => {
        console.log('\tupdating a starts.');
        setA(2);
        console.log('\tupdating a ends.');
        console.log('\tupdating b starts.');
        setB(12);
        console.log('\tupdating b ends.');
    };
    console.log('app rendering ends.');
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div>a is {a}</div>
            <div>b is {b}</div>
            <button onClick={() => {
                console.log('--------------sync click--------------');
                updateState();
            }}>Update State a & b Sync</button>
            <button onClick={() => {
                console.log('--------------async click--------------');
                setTimeout(updateState, 0)
            }}>Update State a & b Async</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Both buttons execute the same code, but in a different way.
Sync button result:

```
app rendering starts.
app rendering ends.
--------------sync click--------------
    updating a starts.
    updating a ends.
    updating b starts.
    updating b ends.
app rendering starts.
app rendering ends.
```

Async button result:

```
app rendering starts.
app rendering ends.
--------------async click--------------
    updating a starts.
app rendering starts.
app rendering ends.
    updating a ends.
    updating b starts.
app rendering starts.
app rendering ends.
    updating b ends.
```

Is this a desired behavior?
How can I have a sync result in an async function?
I could not find any tips about this in official documents.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: This is a really good catch. I tried it on Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-curie-u8zhs?file=/src/App.js:0-1314 and was surprised to see the results. Having a `sync` call runs all `setState` functions in one go and then rerenders. On the other hand, `async` call did it in 2 parts. Really needs an explanation!

Comment: "Is this a desired behavior?" -> This is expected behavior; whether or not it's desired depends on what you're trying to do. "How can I have sync result in an async function?" -> What do you mean?

Comment: first I do not understand why this is happening and second there is no need to re-render the component after each set calling. It is better to re render once and at last. like the sync function.

Comment: Regarding your comment, look at this discussion for v18 : https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a known fact according to [Github discussions](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259).

One of the comments, which I thinks is pretty self explanatory:

> React currently will batch state updates if they're triggered from within a React-based event, like a button click or input change. It will not batch updates if they're triggered outside of a React event handler, like a setTimeout().

React internally uses `unstable_batchedUpdates()`. You can pass in a callback function and state updates inside that will be batched. This does not happen automatically for timeouts, promises, and async functions. So they are called from outside the callback and state updates inside them are not batched.

```
import { unstable_batchedUpdates } from "react-dom";
```

```
const updateState = () => {
    unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
      console.log("\tupdating a starts.");
      setA(2);
      console.log("\tupdating a ends.");
      console.log("\tupdating b starts.");
      setB(12);
      console.log("\tupdating b ends.");
    });
  };
```

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-fast-i1svo?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You may use single `useState()` or `useReducer()` hooks call to update multiple state values by storing them together instead of storing it in separate state slices.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({a: 1, b: 11});

setValues({a: 2, b: 12});
```

Comment: Good solution for this particular problem. but It has two major problem. first, It is not easy to use this solution in my problem(real one). It has multiple hooks and dependencies, merging states cause redundant renders.
second, It will be hard to edit the code. because you must change the merging variables if your implementation changes and this solution affects the props if you get them from parent component.

Comment: You may use `React.memo()` or `useMemo()` hook to avoid unnecessary re-renders. If that's what your concern is with your problem.

Comment: Anyways, from React 18 all state update inside of timeouts, promises, native event handlers or any other event will batch the same way as updates inside 
of React events. Which means, synchronous and asynchronous all. `unstable_batchedUpdates` API will still exist in React 18. But, it might get removed in a 
future version.
Refer:
https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21